# Change the input language to english when shift is pressed

Tags: text-input

On Windows and Linux, when I'm typing in Hebrew and pressing the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, the input language automatically changes to upper case English (just while the shift is pressed, when I let it go it changes back to Hebrew).

Is this possible on OS X also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution.. Switching to 'Hebrew - PC' keyboard instead of 'Hebrew' solved it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **caps-lock** to enable a "second input layer" besides the Hebrew one.

On my system (Mavericks) the following applies if the Hebrew input source is the only available (besides the English one):

Normal Hebrew keyboard layout:

[image]

If you **activate caps-lock** you can enable an English keyboard layer while using the Hebrew input source. The English keyboard layer works normally then: lower case English:

[image]

To enter upper case English you have to press the shift key additionally:

[image]

---

If you enable a third input source (in my example French) in the System Preferences switching first to French and then to Hebrew **activating caps-lock** will show a French layer:

[image]

If you press the shift key additionally you will get upper key French.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath, I knew that caps-lock does that, but it isn't as comfortable as using the shift key since I'm using this feature a lot and I don't want to turn it on and off each time.

Comment: You are right, I had never seen that.  On Hebrew (but not Hebrew PC or Hebrew Qwerty), the caps lock will shift to the last used Latin layout.  I wonder how they do that, it defies everything I know about how keyboard layouts are constructed.

Comment: @TomGewecke This also works with the Georgian and the Myanmar input source (I haven't tested all but most non-latin input sources don't provide this feature). I guess it's related to the common use of/relation to latin alphabets in those languages/areas (Hebrew -> Yiddish; Georgian -> English?; Myanmar -> English).

Comment: it's long been common to have Latin available via capslock on certain keyboards.  But how you can have the layout change depend on an earlier event is a mystery.  These are normally just xml files which have no obvious way to refer to which keyboard was used just before.